# pyspark: Can't correctly decode ISO-8859-1 file using sc.textFile

Tags: python, encoding, pyspark, databricks, iso-8859-1

I need to read a csv file that is enconded with **"ISO-8859-1"** but when using the **sc.TextFile** it does not give me an argument/option to choose my encoding method. Because of that, some of my string comes with

*Not using read.csv() because the file has a double delimiter, so i need to do some work around since pyspark doesn't accept double delimiters.*

Code being used:

```
df_x = (
    spark
    .createDataFrame(
        sc.textFile(path, use_unicode=True)
        .map(lambda line: line.replace("\t", ""))
        .map(lambda line: line.split("@|"))
        , schema = config["report"]["schema"]
        )
    )
```

current output (portuguese):

```
R. GERALDO RODRIGUES DA SILVA 112
RUA ANT�NIO GON�ALVES FILHO 91
Jos� Gon�alves Borges 391
SALDANHA MARINHO 522
```

The expected output should be:

```
R. GERALDO RODRIGUES DA SILVA 112
RUA ANTÔNIO GONÇALVES FILHO 91
José Gonçalves Borges 391
SALDANHA MARINHO 522
```

Comment: Spark doesn't support it: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-1849 - you can try to use Hadoop API instead

Comment: isn't there a way of enconding/decoding after? Or a function to replace this wrongly decoded characters? For examaple, another .map function ?

i've tried < .encode('ascii', 'ignore') > but this will only delete the character, not replace or fix

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for the encoding. The main issue was the python, spark and scala version (databricks runtime).

As per the solution, we updated databricks to python 3.7, spark 3.0 and scala 2.12 and wrote the following code?

```
dff = (
    spark 
    .read 
    .load(
        "path"
        , encoding = "ISO-8859-1"
        , format   = 'csv'
        , sep = '@|'
        , schema = "schema"))
```